# Leaving "Possible duplicate of..." comment caused "you have already raised flag" when trying to flag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, duplicate-questions, rate-limiting

Recently, I have been reaching my daily flag limit frequently.

A few days ago, I had reached it, and then spotted a duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832722/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-a-frame). I commented that it was, by chance using the same wording as the comment that is automatically generated when you raise a 'duplicate' flag:

[image]

The next day, I went back to it to flag it, and the system said I had already raised the flag. This makes it seem as though I accidentally managed to bypass the daily flag limit:

[image]

Did I? Does this mean that it is possible to raise as many duplicate flags as you like?

As you can see from the pictures, the flag and the comment are recorded as the same time, to the highest precision now available.
To people adding answers, I know I didn't flag it as well, since that would auto-generate another comment.

Comment: This looks like a bug indeed, but the title is misleading.

Comment: @user202729 Feel free to edit/suggest to me a better one, it was the best way I could think of to phrase it.

Comment: ... [Leaving "Possible duplicate of..." comment cause "you have already raised flag" warning when flagging]? Something like that.

Comment: What is the exact date of your flag? You can find that by hovering over the word yesterday. Your comment was left on: 2018-04-14 17:28:34Z

Comment: @animuson if that flag that is shown in the screenshot of the OP is legit, I'm wondering why I can't find a review task for it. I always assumed that a close flag would generate a close vote review task after 15 minutes or so when the create review task batch runs. The flagged question already seem to have 2 *close* flags but no corresponding [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/history) AFAICT. I admit what the OP describes is for sure no-repro but it looks like there is *something* off with that question and the flags it took.

Comment: @rene https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19435551

Comment: Oh, it doesn't turn-up in history because no one reviewed it yet. :(

Answer (score 5):

Both the close flag and the comment were created at exactly the same time, indicating you did flag for closure and it created the comment for you automatically. We do not automatically create flags from comment text.

There isn't anything to look at here. What you describe simply is not possible, nor anywhere close to what happened. We make mistakes, we forget things. You clearly did one of those two things, and there's really nothing else to talk about here.

Answer (score -1):

> This makes it seem as though I accidentally managed to bypass the
>   daily flag limit. Did I? Does this mean that it is possible to raise
>   as many duplicate flags as you like?

The system comments are created from a flag/close vote, it won't create a flag or close vote based on a comment. Your comment is just a comment, that happens to be exactly the same as the one the system generates.

I would say that you had raised a flag previously and forgot about it, or some other mistake or scenario that negates any possibility that your comment raised a flag or close vote.

Perhaps you did it in a review and it was concluded by other reviewers to leave it open? In that case you won't see close votes or flag count but also you won't be able to re-flag for the same reason.

---

With regards to the system adding a vote count to flags or close votes from a comment:

1. Potentially allows user to be able to bypass privilege requirements
2. How would the system determine which of a flag or a close vote it is (or something else)
3. If the system did pick up such things from an *identical* comment, this would be entirely pointless functionality to implement and maintain as we already have system based reporting tools. Which is entirely quicker and easier to use than it would be writing out a comment and styling it the same as the system generated one for it to "pick it up" and raise a flag vote

Comment: With regard to No.2, the point of my question is that it was identical to the comment auto-generated by a duplicate flag.

Comment: Ok sure, but the system is not going to perform flag and close actions (even if just vote count increment) based on text in comments.

Comment: I have checked my flag history, I had reached my flag limit before I marked it as duplicate.

Comment: @rene No, it is there but after I had reached my limit

Comment: @rene 13 - I have 40 helpful flags and 1 declined

Comment: @ArtemisFowl What...? Are you sure that you don't make a mistake? When was the flag raised?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl ("yesterday" (the day you left the comment) or "today" (the day you try to flag again)?) If it's "today" then probably you accidentally flagged twice.

Comment: If the flag is in your flag history you obviously did flag it, which explains why you can't flag it again. The system guards your flag limit so it doesn't really matter if you think you hit the limit or not. The system took your flag and now it functions as designed.

Comment: @rene I know my flag has worked, that's not the question. The question  asked why.

Comment: @user202729 You can't flag twice, and that's a big part of the question

Comment: @ArtemisFowl because you miscalculated your flag limit. That is why.

Comment: @rene No, because yesterday, when I added the comment, I had tried to add it as a flag, but the system told me I had reached my limit. Also, I would know if I had flagged it as well as posting the comment since it would auto-generate another comment.

Comment: Maybe you raised a different flag. What a mess. It is status-norepro already. We're done here.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Probably because flag reached a limit on a day will be automatically raised on the next day.

Comment: @rene is there such a thing?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Also, can you check your flag history to see when was the flag raised?

Comment: @user202729 no, there is not.

Comment: @user202729 have added pics showing that both were yesterday.