# Should we change the description of spam?

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

The description of spam when you currently flag is 'Exits only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation', which does not cover simply random posts, such as:

i love you, i love you, i love you, etc.

Which I recently encountered (as an audit). I flagged it as 'has nothing to do with programming' which was fine, but feel that it should come 'spam'.

Comment: I have the wrong definition of spam. Done.

Comment: Since my cross site duplicate link was auto-deleted, let me try again: [Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam)

Comment: @psubsee2003 That was weird. Was it just because your comment had the word 'duplicate' in it?

Comment: @BSMP so does the new one

Comment: Yes, but they posted that comment after the duplicate notice was placed on the question. The comments that got auto-deleted were added before the notice.

Comment: @BSMP That's interesting. Also could be related to my question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366039/leaving-possible-duplicate-of-comment-caused-you-have-already-raised-flag (status norepro)

Comment: @BSMP I think that's a known issue.  I remember seeing that before with the word duplicate and a link.  Have to see if i can find it.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I don't believe that is the case.  I've done that before (leave a manual duplicate comment) and it never causes me to be able to not flag/vote as a duplicate

Comment: @psubsee2003 see the question. I probably made a mistake.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate

Answer (score 7):

> which does not cover simply random posts, such as:
>
> > i love you, i love you, i love you, etc.

Indeed, it doesn't.  That's because that's not spam, and shouldn't be flagged as spam.

You can flag something like that as abusive.

Comment: But it's not abusive. It's just random.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl flag it as Not An Answer. It would so nice to get a NAA flag that was correct ;)

Comment: What about questions

Comment: @ArtemisFowl - Very Low Quality. This is what those flags are designed for. Though with questions you can down-vote and vote to close so they'll disappear much quicker.

Comment: Ok, the answer I think then is VLQ. Also I have the wrong defenition of spam.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl When someone is just posting random text it's pretty clear that they're not doing so in good faith.  They're being deliberately disruptive for the sake of it.  That's abusive.

Comment: Ah. Abusive of the system rather than anyone in particular.

Comment: Google defines abusive as 'extremely offensive and insulting.' which this wouldn't be.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Taken out of context, perhaps not, but in context, it's clear that it's sole purpose is to be disruptive and to waste people's time.  It's goal is solely to cause harm to people.  That's abusive.